# Open links of iframe in a new tab of the parent page

Tags: html

I have a website which contains an iframe to load another website. When a user is clicking a link in the iframe, the navigation is happening inside the iframe which is fine. However, when a user opens a link in a new tab (e.g. with the mouse wheel) the direct link is opened and the parent site is gone. The problem is that I need the new tab to open in the parent otherwise the page will fail over time (the parent page is for example handling authentication). Is there a possibility to achieve this? I have full control over both websites.